# I tried with this code, but it won't work with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

> PS C:\Users\USER\PickMeUp> typings install google.maps --ambient --save
>   typings ERR! deprecated The "ambient" flag is deprecated. Please use "global" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
C:\Users\USER\PickMeUp> typings install google.maps --global --save typings
```

it just means you have to replace --ambient with --global flag

Comment: i ll try ..thnk u so much

Comment: @KalanaDilshan for this at least that's what the instruction says. ionic 3 have to check